# Создание разных контекстов подключения в зависимости от значения поля в структуре

Tags: golang

Вот что-то туплю, есть ф-ция в которую приходит структура и которая возвращает контекст готового подключения, если в ф-цию приходит bool TLS true то нужно создать констекст с TLS, если false то простое подключение, собственно вопрос как это сделать, простым if нельзя ибо блочная видимость.
Собственно нужно что-то типа того, код нерабочий, просто для понимания того что нужно

```
if UseTLS == true {
client, err := pop3.DialTLS("domain.com:995")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }   
} else {
client, err := pop3.Dial("domain.com:110")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
// а далее например 
err = client.User("user@domain.com")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
// и т.д.
```

Используется библиотека [go-pop3](https://github.com/bytbox/go-pop3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объявите переменную вне блока

```
var client *pop3.Client
var err error // если ранее не объявлялась

if UseTLS == true {
client, err = pop3.DialTLS("domain.com:995")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }   
} else {
client, err = pop3.Dial("domain.com:110")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
// а далее например 
err = client.User("user@domain.com")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
// и т.д.   }
}
```

Comment: Добавил пояснения в вопрос, пробовал так делать, но не получилось, выдавало ошибку что объект ctx не имеет метода Value

Comment: Поправил ответ под вопрос. Суть та же - просто объявите переменную отдельно, вне блока кода. И := замените на = - чтобы определять значение переменных, но не переопределять сами переменные внутри блока.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает :)